# what should use instead of .show() and .hide() in microsoft Internet explorer browser?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

i want show the option values which have class containing german when i click german button , viceversa for english  ..

Below codes are working fine in chrome . i want to see the result in internet explorer . how to acheive this ?

note :- while running this in IE .hide changes as display:none , and .show changes as display:inline

```js
$(".german").hide();
$(".english").show();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="num">
    <option value="1" selected class="english"> One</option>
    <option value="2" class="english"> Two</option>

    <option value="1" selected class="german"> One(german)</option>
    <option value="2" class="german"> Two(german)</option>

</select>
```

Comment: You tried on Explorer and it isn't working ?

Comment: yes my dear @Pleasure

Comment: Can you please check if your doctype is valid

Comment: am running this code in visual studio @Pleasure

Comment: Instead of `hide()` and `show()`, use `attr("style", "display: none;")` and `attr("style", "display: block;") `.

Comment: What do you mean by "changes" ? Also you can use `toggle()`

Comment: CHANGES refer to while seeing in INSPECT ELEMENT  @Pleasure

Comment: In a <select> a better approach is to use append() and remove() if you would change the elements inside it.

Comment: Alright then and with `toggle()` from `jQuery` ?

Comment: You can also use `$(".german").addClass("hide");`
`$(".english").removeClass("hide");` and in CSS `.hide {display: none}`

Comment: please give any examples . am new to jquery

Answer (score 0):

First you add ready() method in your script

```
 $( document ).ready( function() {
  $(".german").hide();
  $(".english").show();
 });
```

**OR**

```
 $( document ).ready( function() {
  if($.browser.msie){
  $('.english').css({"visibility":"visible"});
  }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function toEnglish() {
    //reset select
    $(".german").remove();
    $(".english").remove();

    //add english elements
    $("#num").append($("<option>").attr({value: "1", class: "english"}).html("One"));
    $("#num").append($("<option>").attr({value: "2", class: "english"}).html("Two"));
}

function toGerman() {
    //reset select
    $(".german").remove();
    $(".english").remove();

    //add german elements
    $("#num").append($("<option>").attr({value: "1", class: "german"}).html("One (german)"));
    $("#num").append($("<option>").attr({value: "2", class: "german"}).html("Two (german)"));
}
```

Here an example https://jsfiddle.net/jxjovfs5/1/